# dynamically generated select / options empty in IE but OK in other browsers

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I'm generating a 'select' element then populating it with options and inserting it into the DOM of my page. Everything's fine in FF, Chrome, Chromium etc. but in IE no options show in the drop-down list but highlights show under the cursor and when I click in the blank list the event handler gets triggered and processes correctly.
Here's the relevant HTML area:

```
<span id="spn_fyear" style="position:absolute; top:7px; left:200px; height:24px; cursor:pointer; color:#000000;" onclick="spn_fyear_onclick(this)">
   <span id="spn_fyearno" style="position:absolute; top:0px; font:italic bold 17px sans-serif; color:#FFFEF2;"><?=$thisPage->getVar('start_year')?></span>
</span>
```

and here's the javascript in question:

```
function spn_fyear_onclick(_obj)
{
    //make start year list
    var lstto = document.getElementById('lst_year');
    var topts = new Array();
    var nopt = null;
    for(i=0; i<lstto.options.length; i++)
    {
        topts[i] = lstto.options[i].text;
    }
    var lstf = document.createElement('SELECT');
    lstf.id = "lst_fyear";
    lstf.style.position = "absolute";
    lstf.style.top = "-3px";
    lstf.style.left = "1px";
    lstf.style.fontFamily = "sans-serif";
    lstf.style.fontWeight = "normal";
    lstf.style.fontSize = "12px ";
    lstf.style.width = "55px";
    lstf.style.color = "#000000";
    lstf.style.display = "inline";
    lstf.onchange = lst_fyear_onchange;
    for(i = 0; i < topts.length; i++)
    {
        if(topts[i] != 'undefined')
        {
        nopt = document.createElement('OPTION');
        nopt.text = topts[i];
        nopt.value = topts[i];
        lstf.appendChild(nopt);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('spn_fyear').appendChild(lstf);
}
```

In this line: `var lstto = document.getElementById('lst_year')`
I'm creating a reference to an existing select object from which I copy the option data. lst_year gets populated by a php database query when the page first loads. I created the array (`var topts = new Array()`) in desperation in case IE has a quirk which copies attributes and properties but to no avail. Like I said - everything works like a dream in FF or Chrome both in Linux and Windoze but falls in a heap with IE. I've scoured MSDN etc. for some obscure behaviour but I'm stumped. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)
Kind regards,
Jen

Comment: As an aside -- it is MUCH better to style elements with CSS and then just set the .className property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, your problem is here:

```
    nopt = document.createElement('OPTION');
```

Try this method mentioned here:

[JavaScript: add extra attribute after new Option()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499019/javascript-add-extra-attribute-after-new-option)

(I've had a lot of problem with `<option>` elements and IE before until I started using the `new Option` constructor.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.
Still can't see why some normal DOM references to object properties and methods don't work and others do .....

Comment: @user2009515 I understand.  Sometimes though, I just get to the point of just accepting what works and not thinking about it anymore.