# <option> value is not shown in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, combobox, dojo

I created a dojo widget for my project that represents some data as a `<select>` content. It is populated with the following code:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= this.pageCount; i++) {
    var opt = dojo.doc.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i.toString();
    opt.text = i.toString();
    dojo.place(opt, select);
}
```

It works fine with Mozilla, but `<select>` is empty in IE. But what should I do to make it work in IE?

Comment: If you are testing on IE9+ you can have a look at the developer tools (press f12) and take a look at the console for errors

Comment: Have you tried creating a new Option DOM and then appending?e.g. var obj1 = new Option("key","value");

Comment: Console shows nothing. `var opt = dojo.doc.createElement('option');` is the code that creates new DOM node.

Comment: IE8 has a bug creating a DOM node directly :See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591707/dynamically-generated-select-options-empty-in-ie-but-ok-in-other-browsers

Comment: The result is the same, text is not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed

```
opt.text = i.toString();
```

to

```
opt.innerHTML = i.toString();
```

and it began to work in all browsers.