# javascript dropdown options is not in order

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu

i have a javascript it dropdown the year when i  select a year and it dropdown the remaining year but it is not in a appropriate order.so please any one help to rectify the problem.eg. if there is 3 years 2013,2014,2015  i selected 2015 it drops `2015,2013,2014` i want to display like `2013 2014 2015`

```
<select class="inputmedium" name="year_<?php echo $row->id; ?>" id="year_<?php echo $row->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $row->year; ?>"><option ><?php echo $row->year; ?></option>
        <script>
var min = new Date().getFullYear(),
    max = min + 9,
    select = document.getElementById('year_<?php echo $row->id; ?>');

for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
    if (i == <?php echo $row->year; ?>) {
        continue;
    }
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.innerHTML = i;
    select.appendChild(opt);
}
</script>
</select>
```

Comment: The value of a select element is the value (or text if there is no value) of the currently selected option. Setting the value attribute of the select itself may be confusing.

Comment: I've always had the oddest things happen when I used `createElement('option')`  I always recommend using `new Option()` like in this syntax: (here)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499019/javascript-add-extra-attribute-after-new-option].

Comment: Your problem is the first `<option>`. I suspect it is different from `min`. Your loop is fine, which is why `2013`, `2014', and `2014`, `2015` are correct. It's the first year that's the oddball.
Shouldn't `min` be `$row->year`?