# Populate preselected values to Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to populate some preselected values to [Select2](https://select2.org). My code is like below.

```
(function($) {  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".volunteer").on("click", function (event) {

      let element_id = event.target.id;
      // Check if select is already loaded
      if (!$(this).has("select").length) {
        var cellEle = $(this);

        // Populate select element
        cellEle.html(`<select multiple="multiple"></select>`);

        // Initialise select2
        let selectEle = cellEle.children("select").select2({
          allowClear: true,
          maximumSelectionLength: 3,
          ajax: {
            url: "/wordpressbosta/matt/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (params) {
              return { 
                        action: 'get_data',
                    };
            },
            type: "post",
            processResults: function (data) { 
              var options = [];
              if ( data ) {
                $.each( data, function( index, text ) {
                  options.push({ id: index, text: text });
                });
              }
              return {
                results: options
              };
            }
          }
        });

        selectEle.select2('open');

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          url: "/wordpressbosta/matt/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
          data: { 
            element_id: element_id,
            action: 'get_preselect_values',
          },
          success: function (data) {
            var options = [];
              
            if (data) {
              $.each( data, function( index, text ) {
                options.push({ id: index, text: text });
              });
            }
            
            selectEle.val(options).trigger('change'); // I am trying to attach value here. But it is not working. 
          }
        });


        selectEle.on('select2:select', function () {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: "/wordpressbosta/matt/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: { 
              selected_items: selectEle.val(),
              element_id: element_id,
              action: 'save_data'
            }
          });
        });

        selectEle.on("select2:unselecting", function () {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: "/wordpressbosta/matt/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: { 
              selected_items: selectEle.val(),
              task_id: element_id,
              action: 'save_data'
            } 
          });
        }).trigger('change');
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

I am trying to attach values but it is not working.

I am trying to something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/h92jmy2w).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options should be appended to the select element rather than selected with `.val()`. Details on this can be found in the documetation [here](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#preselecting-options-in-an-remotely-sourced-ajax-select2).

An updated snippet of the code to `.append` the preselected values:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "url",
  data: {
    element_id: element_id,
    action: "get_preselect_values",
  },
  success: function (data) {              
    if (data) {
      $.each( data, function( index, text ) {                
        // Declare a new Option for the value - Note id is set to text
        const option = new Option(text, text, true, true);
        // Append the value to the select element
        selectEle.append(option).trigger('change');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Please note the `id` of the preselected values must match the `id` of the retrieved list of values. The `id` in the question is the index of the item in the array, whcih won't match the preselected index. If these values don't match you'll be able to select preselected items twice.

To ensure the values match you could update your code to set the `id` to the same string as the `text`. This would need to be done when adding values `options.push({ id: text, text: text });`. It must also be done when preselecting values as per the example above `new Option(text, text, true, true);` where `text` is passed as both the text and value of the [Option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option).

Additionally you may wish to load the already selected values before initailising select2, otherwise the values may appear after select2 has opened which could cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Please note the id of the preselected values must match the id of the retrieved list of values. The id in the question is the index of the item in the array, whcih won't match the preselected index. If these values don't match you'll be able to select preselected items twice.

************
Important words.

Comment: Thanks @Chris C. How can I send extra data with this new option `const option = new Option(text, text, true, true);`  ?

Comment: I would suggest adding as described in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5499053/1620449 for example option.setAttribute("key","value");

Comment: Thanks again @Chris C. Can I use like this `var o1 = new Option("key","value");
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = o1;
o1.setAttribute("value", 123456);` ? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Chris C. I made a post regarding this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71369437/send-extra-data-to-template-in-select2-for-preselected-vallues