# Add attributes to <option> from javascript

Tags: javascript, attributes

I have this piece of JS:

```
for(var index in response.rates) {
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option([index], index);
}
```

It generates the  and  tags populated with an array.

How can I give attributes to  from there? Like onselect and and other things.

Comment: Change `[index]` to just `index`

Comment: May be this can help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499019/javascript-add-extra-attribute-after-new-option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the option to a variable then you can give it attributes.

```
for(var index in response.rates) {
    let option = new Option(index, index);
    option.addEventListener("select", ...);
    select.options[select.options.length] = option;
}
```